# Missing required entitlement for NFCTagReaderSession

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am trying to launch communication by corenfc using the ISO7816, but I always get the same error, even though I tried several requests posted on the internet.

the code is

```
@IBAction func scanPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        nfcSession = NFCTagReaderSession.init(pollingOption: .iso14443, delegate: self)
        nfcSession?.alertMessage = "Hold your IPhone near the ISO7816 tag to begin transaction.";
        nfcSession?.begin()
    }
```

and my info.plist is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.iso7816.select-identifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>D2760000850101</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.formats</key>
    <array>
      <string>NDEF</string>
      <string>TAG</string>
    </array>  
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NFCReaderUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Message in a Card</string>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
        <string>nfc</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I get the following error

> The session was invalidated: Error Domain=NFCError Code=2 "Missing required entitlement" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Missing required entitlement}

How could it be solved?

Comment: have fixed this issues ?

Answer (score 0):

Your entitlements should be located in a file named NFCTagReaders.entitlements and it should contains the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.formats</key>
    <array>
        <string>NDEF</string>
        <string>TAG</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

I'm not sure why in your case it's contained in the main Info.plist file.
It may be related with you're issue, as your configurations looks correct.

Info.plist and NFCTagReaders.entitlements files:

[image: screenshot Info.plist and NFCTagReaders.entitlements files]

Please check as well that the NFC capabilities is activated in the project configuration.

You should also check before starting the session that the NFC session is available by adding these lines :

```
guard NFCTagReaderSession.readingAvailable else {
        print("NFC Session not available")
        return
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

"com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.iso7816.select-identifiers" setting in infos.plist must be correct.It will be error when you set a wrong AID.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).